# How do I merge two tables and divide numerical instances from a previous value count in each cell in Python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge, dataframe

how I got a new table that shows how occurrences that Tennis was and was not played during each type of weather condition from the table.

---

```
labels = ["Outlook","Temperature","PlayTennis", "Value"]
data = [["Sunny",60,"Yes",1]
       ,["Sunny",70,"Yes",1]
       ,["Sunny",40,"No",1]
       ,["Overcast",40,"No",1]
       ,["Overcast",60,"Yes",1]
       ,["Overcast",50,"Yes",1]
       ,["Overcast",70,"Yes",1]
       ,["Overcast",80,"Yes",1]
       ,["Rainy",65,"No",1]
       ,["Rainy",70,"Yes",1]]
```

thats what the data is but I am reading from a csv file

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Tennis.csv')
df.columns.values

# Count the number of positive and negative values in PlayTennis and display them
# as yes or no.
vc = df['PlayTennis'].value_counts()


#create a new pivoted displaying value of PlayTennis as columns versus Outlook as rows 
pivoted = pd.pivot_table(df,
                         rows=['Outlook'],
                         cols=['PlayTennis'],
                         aggfunc=sum)
```

---

Now I need to divide the table I obtained in from the results of the prior count of the yes and no's in the csv table. So the result will be a table which has the exact same rows and columns from the pivoted table, but the values in each of the cells should be normalized to the prior count. For example: the cell corresponding to Sunny and Yes must have the number of instances where Outlook was Sunny and PlayTennis was Yes, divided by the total number of instances wher PlayTennis was Yes.

I figured the logic to this would be to merge original table with pivoted table and have each cell with a numerical dividing each particular sum of instances by the value.count of the PlayTennis responses, but I just don't know the syntax for it.

I just roughly plugged this in as a frail idea but obviously gave me an error:

```
Finaldf = pd.pivot_table(pivoted,
                         rows=['Outlook'],
                         cols=['PlayTennis'] + /= ,
                         aggfunc=sum)

#display new pivoted table
Finaldf
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I get when I run your code and print the result:

```
>>> print pivoted

           Temperature      Value    
PlayTennis          No  Yes    No Yes
Outlook                              
Overcast            40  260     1   4
Rainy               65   70     1   1
Sunny               40  130     1   2
```

If I understand correctly, you want the cells under 'Value' to display proportions where each column adds to one. To do this, you can simply divide those columns by a Series containing your counts, which you have already calculated:

```
>>> pivoted['Value'] = pivoted['Value'] / vc
>>> print pivoted

           Temperature          Value          
PlayTennis          No  Yes        No       Yes
Outlook                                        
Overcast            40  260  0.333333  0.571429
Rainy               65   70  0.333333  0.142857
Sunny               40  130  0.333333  0.285714
```

Now you might have wanted to do this to the whole table. I can't image why you would, which is why I assumed you just wanted to do this to the columns under 'Values'. However, if you did want to do this to the whole table, you can of course do exactly the same thing to the 'Temperatures' columns. Or, even better, you can do this:

```
>>> pivoted = pivoted.div(vc, level=1)
>>> print pivoted

           Temperature                Value          
PlayTennis          No        Yes        No       Yes
Outlook                                              
Overcast     13.333333  37.142857  0.333333  0.571429
Rainy        21.666667  10.000000  0.333333  0.142857
Sunny        13.333333  18.571429  0.333333  0.285714
```

The other thing you might have wanted to do is to calculate the mean values for the 'Temperature' columns, while calculating the proportions under 'Values'. This would make a bit more sense. To do this, you can use different aggfuncs when you create your initial pivot table, as follows:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> pivoted = pd.pivot_table(df,
...                          index=['Outlook'],
...                          columns=['PlayTennis'],
...                          aggfunc={'Temperature': np.mean, 'Value': sum})
>>> pivoted = pivoted.div(vc, level=1)
>>> print pivoted

           Temperature         Value          
PlayTennis          No Yes        No       Yes
Outlook                                       
Overcast            40  65  0.333333  0.571429
Rainy               65  70  0.333333  0.142857
Sunny               40  65  0.333333  0.285714
```

Hopefully one of those is what you wanted to do.